# Subscribe non-exposed NodeJS Application to SNS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

On my current architecture, I have a NodeJS application that posts a message on SQS, which triggers a lambda function that (finally) puts the result on MongoDB. While the lambda is running, the NodeJS app pools MongoDB until the status field changes to `SUCCESS` or `FAILED`.

I would like to change this architecture to be event-driven rather than relying on pooling. To achieve that I considered changing both the NodeJS app to subscribe to a SNS topic and the Lambda function to post the result to that topic.

However, I faced a challenge when attempting to subscribe to the SNS topic. The `subscribe` method demands an `Endpoint` to confirm the subscription, and the NodeJS in question is not exposed (it's not an API). So how could the subscription be confirmed?

I understand that AWS might want to avoid spams by implementing subscription confirmation for SMS and Email, but on this case, the subscriber is a simple application...

Is there any way to subscribe tot he topic without exposing the NodeJS application? Or SNS is not the appropriate solution here?

I have used RabbitMQ for this on the past, but I would rather not deploy an instance and instead leverage a platform-as-a-service type of product.

Comment: *"The subscribe method demands an Endpoint to confirm the subscription"* - it requires an endpoint to later send messages to, unrelated to the confirmation. If SNS cannot reach your application how is it supposed to send you notifications? Subscribe a queue and poll from that queue. Wether you poll or get notified has little to with wether or not your system can be called event-driven or not. You cannot subscribe to SNS without offering a reachable endpoint. Most normal MQ systems use polling as well because there is not really an alternative, maybe websockets (which is basically long polling)

Comment: @luk2302 what most messaging platforms do, is to simply maintain a websocket-like connection alive which they can send notifications to (definitely not http). If you are subscribing to RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ you don't need to expose an endpoint to get the response. So isn't that possible with aws sns? Websockets and http pooling are severely different approaches with way different response times and performance, you made them look like the same.

Comment: No, not possible with SNS.